# Build failed - flutter.gradle

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, flutter-dependencies

Flutter run produces the following error:

Target debug_android_application failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files.
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script '/Users/kirk/Developer/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 896
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

  > Process 'command '/Users/kirk/Developer/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Any potential solutions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have face similar issues so after spending lot of time i have found if we can write full path for assests file then it works please check below example how it is defined.

```
 assets:
   - assets/bg_screen_page.png
   - assets/logo.png
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you have compatibility issues between the build tools located in android/build.gradle and the gradle located in android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties, try upgrade or downgrade one of them to be compatible with the other, check this table for compatibilites: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin[compatibilites](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem where I couldn't compile or debug my Flutter app. To solve this, just go to tools and in Flutter selection, click on *{open project for editing in Android Studio}*. This will open only the Android counterpart and you will be able to update your gradle dependencies once the analysis is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Target debug_android_application failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files.

This issue belong to "pubspec.yaml" file. Notices that if your declare the assets file in such manner (assets/icons/catogories). So just add "/" in the end. It basically target the folder, not the files inside of it

it should be look like that: "assets/icons/catogories/"